# How to do oneliner code with loop and condition?

Tags: c#, syntax, foreach

How will i make this an oneliner code?

```
int result = 0;
if (directory.Files.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (var file in directory.Files)
    {
        result += file.FileCommits.Count() > 0 ? file.FileCommits.Last().LinesOfCode : 0;
    }
}
return result;
```

Comment: Don´t use `Count()` to check if a collection contains items. Use `Any` instead as it will return `true` if just one item was found instead of fully enumerating the whole collection.

Comment: You don't need `if` block. If it has no items it will not enter the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 7):

What you're doing is collecting the sum lines of code. You can use [`Enumerable.Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534734(v=vs.100).aspx) for that (optimized in curtsy of @ScottChamberlain):

```
var sum = directory.Files.Sum(file => 
                              file.FileCommits.Select(commit => commit.LinesOfCode)
                                              .LastOrDefault())
```

Comment: What happened to the loop? how will i get the file inside of the directory? Because the loop is not there anymore.

Comment: The loop disappeared, as you don't need it anymore. `Enumerable.Sum` will iterate each item is `directory.Files` (just like `foreach`). It will then, for each file, invoke the predicate provided to it. If you're not familiar with LINQ, I'd advise you to start reading about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)

Comment: The Sum could be simplified to `directory.Files.Sum(file => file.FileCommits.Select(commit => commit.LinesOfCode).LastOrDefault())`, assuming `LinesOfCode` is a `int` or some other type who's `default(T)` value is `0`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You're right. That would be more efficient as well. I'll modify.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach:

```
var sum = directory.Files.Where(file => file.FileCommits.Any())
                         .Sum(file => file.FileCommits.Last().LineOfCode);
```